# 2Wire router port forwarding

Tags: networking, port, subsonic, router

I am having some trouble allowing my 2wire router (provided by AT&T to forward certain ports.

I have a raspberry pi running subsonic (a music server) and I would like to access it from the outside internet. I have configured the pi with a static LAN IP address and have opened the specified ports (4040 and 80) on both TCP and UDP. I have also confirmed the service is active and is listening on the specified ports via netstat.

When I attempt to connect, however, from my WAN IP I am confronted with a connection refused dialog. Checking the firewall logs on my router, I see this message

```
IN=br1 MAC=--:--:--:--:--:-- SRC=(my computer IP) DST=(My WAN IP) LEN=40 TTL=240 PROTO=TCP DPT=5060 Unknown inbound session stopped
```

It appears that my firewall is still blocking the external connection. What strikes me as odd is, although I am unable to connect I can still see that the port is open from an outside port scanner. Using the service provided from http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ I have confirmed that my IP has port 4040 to be open.

Once again, I have confirmed that the service is indeed listening on the raspberry pi, setup a static LAN address and created the protocol for both TCP and UDP....

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: I just noticed on my firewall log that it seems the request is coming through on port 5060, which would explain why it is refusing the connection. I am certain that I am submitting the request for port 4040 however. So I honestly have no idea why the request is for a different port.

Comment: You are trying to connect on TCP port 5060, but you opened ports 4040 and 80.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. It is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for whatever reason it was working all along. Apparently it was just getting confused by me trying to connect to my own router. I confirmed this by connecting to the server via 4G on my phone.

Dumb mistake by me.